# Specifying sort direction in openFDA queries

Tags: openfda

Is it currently possible to specify a field and sort direction for the openFDA api? I don't see any mentioning of it within the [documentation](https://open.fda.gov/api/reference/).

Answer (score 1):

It does not support sort, although there is some ranking that is done behind the scene; it is the default scoring on Elasticsearch, which is based upon Lucene's similarity algorithm:

http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html